# Why using this in controller

Tags: magento-1.9

I am Beginner of Magento I want to create New Module that time in controller they used some code

```
if ($this->getRequest()->isPost()){
    $int1 = $this->getRequest()->getPost('int1');
    $int2 = $this->getRequest()->getPost('int2');
  }
```

I followed this link http://blog.baobaz.com/en/blog/magento-module-create-your-own-controller

Can you please suggest any basic tutorial for creating form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**`$this->getRequest()->isPost()`** is use for  **check current request type** ***`post method ($_POST)`***

Using `$this->getRequest()->getPost('int1')` is  used for **getting data from  post request.**.Just like php `$_POST['int1']`

### Edited:

as per as your request.

`$this->renderLayout();` get layout output and process this output to response body and append response

`$this->loadLayout();` loading layout and  creates XML tree .

Comment: thanks for quick reply  for this $this->loadLayout();
    $this->_initLayoutMessages('customer/session');
    $this->renderLayout();

Comment: Thanks But i can't understand this $this->loadLayout();